# Azure Traffic Manager TTL - what does it mean for downtime

Tags: load-balancing, azure

The default TTL on Azure Traffic Manager is 5 minutes by default. Does this mean that when a server (endpoint) goes down then people won't get routed to a working server for up to 5 mins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTL or Time To Live is the interval that DNS will be cached. So yes. it takes 5 minutes for them to get redirected (as maximum if the client doesn't use the authoritative DNS server from Azure).